# How do you represent a system of equations with arbitrary rows that follow a pattern?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation, systems-of-equations

I have a system of equations where each equation can be expressed as:

$\sum_{i=1}^n c_iy_i^{k}(t) = \bar{y}_k$

And $k$ represents the $k^{th}$ equation. I am tempted to succinctly write the lot as:

$\Bigg\{_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n c_iy_i^{k}(t) = \bar{y}_k$

As a way to denote the system with n equations.

Is there a standard way to denote this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like $y(t) c = \bar y$ to me, where $y$ is a matrix-valued function and $c, \bar y \in \mathbb R^n$.